# right way to run some code with timeout in Python

Tags: python, windows, multithreading, timeout

I looked online and found some SO discussing and ActiveState recipes for running some code with a timeout. It looks there are some common approaches:

- Use thread that run the code, and `join` it with timeout. If timeout elapsed - kill the thread. This is not directly supported in Python (used private `_Thread__stop` function) so it is **bad practice**
- Use `signal.SIGALRM` - but this approach **not working on Windows**!
- Use subprocess with timeout - but this is **too heavy** - what if I want to start interruptible task often, I don't want fire process for each!

So, what is **the right way**? I'm not asking about workarounds (eg use Twisted and async IO), but actual way to solve actual problem - I have some function and I want to run it only with some timeout. If timeout elapsed, I want control back. And I want it to work on Linux and Windows.

Comment: Killing a code is a bad practice, but threads is the best way if you want to do it.

Comment: I'm assuming you can't modify the code in question?

Comment: @agf: sure can't. otherwise i would not ask

Comment: I think twisted is **not** a workaround, it is **the** solution.

Comment: Can you say exactly you're doing? What does the code you're running do?

Comment: There is no **right way**, it depends on what you're interrupting, what shared state it keeps, etc.

Comment: It depends on your algorithms, if it's something iterative you can yield to give back control, if it's IO you can `select` and so on ...

Comment: @Benjamin: Just curious, that's all. The code actually use socket calls. For now I will maybe switch to Twisted, but wanted to know if timeout is possible instead. It is shame to switch to twisted just for timeout

Comment: I think Thread's `stop` function is depreciated in favor of interrupting the thread and handling the killing of it yourself. Just killing a thread is not bad practice.

Comment: @PiPeep: how do you kill the thread yourself?

Comment: @zaharpopov You just have the thread's `run` function return.

Comment: Ditto to @Useless, totally depends on what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A completely general solution to this *really, honestly* does not exist. You have to use the right solution for a given domain.

- If you want timeouts for code you fully control, you have to write it to cooperate. Such code has to be able to break up into little chunks in some way, as in an event-driven system. You can also do this by threading if you can ensure nothing will hold a lock too long, but handling locks right is actually pretty hard.
- If you want timeouts because you're afraid code is out of control (for example, if you're afraid the user will ask your calculator to compute `9**(9**9)`), you need to run it in another process. This is the only easy way to sufficiently isolate it. Running it in your event system or even a different thread will not be enough. It is also possible to break things up into little chunks similar to the other solution, but requires very careful handling and usually isn't worth it; in any event, that doesn't allow you to do the same exact thing as just running the Python code.

Answer (score 12):

What you might be looking for is the [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool) module. If `subprocess` is too heavy, then this may not suit your needs either.

```
import time
import multiprocessing

def do_this_other_thing_that_may_take_too_long(duration):
    time.sleep(duration)
    return 'done after sleeping {0} seconds.'.format(duration)

pool = multiprocessing.Pool(1)
print 'starting....'
res = pool.apply_async(do_this_other_thing_that_may_take_too_long, [8])
for timeout in range(1, 10):
    try:
        print '{0}: {1}'.format(duration, res.get(timeout))
    except multiprocessing.TimeoutError:
        print '{0}: timed out'.format(duration) 

print 'end'
```

Comment: this makes function run in child process, right? and when timeout error, child process is killed?

Comment: If you want to be able to kill arbitrary code, including C extensions, and have some semblance of cleanup, you need to use processes. If you think they are too slow to fork, then keep one or two pre-spawned children waiting to execute when you need them. `multiprocessing` seems to do just that, so I'm replacing my answer with an upvote for this one.

Comment: @LaC: but the problem with process is - you can't keep it pre-spawned,  because when timeout happens you **kill it**! So where is benefit of pre-spawn here?

Comment: @zaharpopov This depends on your use case - how often do you expect to kill subtasks? I am using code adapted from this answer. In my use case I need to kill maybe 1 in every few thousand runs - not using a pool is *really* slow. If killing is a normal occurrence then it's going to be slow no matter what you do.

Answer (score 6):

If it's network related you could try:

```
import socket
socket.setdefaulttimeout(number)
```

Answer (score 4):

I found this with eventlet library:

http://eventlet.net/doc/modules/timeout.html

```
from eventlet.timeout import Timeout

timeout = Timeout(seconds, exception)
try:
    ... # execution here is limited by timeout
finally:
    timeout.cancel()
```

Comment: Without `eventlet.sleep` this code doesn't work - it requires at least one time of calling this function. Code execution can be intercepted only during this call. I can't see meaning in this module in this case - I can't use it for my code without injecting `eventlet.sleep` each second line.

Answer (score 2):

For "normal" Python code, that doesn't linger prolongued times in C extensions or I/O waits, you can achieve your goal by setting a trace function with `sys.settrace()` that aborts the running code when the timeout is reached.

Whether that is sufficient or not depends on how co-operating or malicious the code you run is. If it's well-behaved, a tracing function is sufficient.

Comment: You excluded the solutions that would handle those.

Comment: and also, I think using `sys.settrace` will make code very slow, no?

Answer (score 2):

An other way is to use [faulthandler](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/faulthandler/):

```
import time
import faulthandler


faulthandler.enable()


try:
    faulthandler.dump_tracebacks_later(3)
    time.sleep(10)
finally:
    faulthandler.cancel_dump_tracebacks_later()
```

N.B: The [faulthandler](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/faulthandler.html) module is part of stdlib in python3.3.

Comment: @zaharpopov: yes it's does; if this is not what you want IMO your best option is to use `subprocess` .

Comment: dump_tracebacks_later is based on signals and thus not available on Windows

Answer (score 0):

If you're running code that you expect to die after a set time, then you should write it properly so that there aren't any negative effects on shutdown, no matter if its a thread or a subprocess. A command pattern with undo would be useful here.

So, it really depends on what the thread is doing when you kill it. If its just crunching numbers who cares if you kill it. If its interacting with the filesystem and you kill it , then maybe you should really rethink your strategy.

What is supported in Python when it comes to threads? Daemon threads and joins. Why does python let the main thread exit if you've joined a daemon while its still active? Because its understood that someone using daemon threads will (hopefully) write the code in a way that it wont matter when that thread dies. Giving a timeout to a join and then letting main die, and thus taking any daemon threads with it, is perfectly acceptable in this context.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved that in that way:
For me is worked great (in windows and not heavy at all) I'am hope it was useful for someone)

```
import threading
import time

class LongFunctionInside(object):
    lock_state = threading.Lock()
    working = False

    def long_function(self, timeout):

        self.working = True

        timeout_work = threading.Thread(name="thread_name", target=self.work_time, args=(timeout,))
        timeout_work.setDaemon(True)
        timeout_work.start()

        while True:  # endless/long work
            time.sleep(0.1)  # in this rate the CPU is almost not used
            if not self.working:  # if state is working == true still working
                break
        self.set_state(True)

    def work_time(self, sleep_time):  # thread function that just sleeping specified time,
    # in wake up it asking if function still working if it does set the secured variable work to false
        time.sleep(sleep_time)
        if self.working:
            self.set_state(False)

    def set_state(self, state):  # secured state change
        while True:
            self.lock_state.acquire()
            try:
                self.working = state
                break
            finally:
                self.lock_state.release()

lw = LongFunctionInside()
lw.long_function(10)
```

The main idea is to create a thread that will just sleep in parallel to "long work" and in wake up (after timeout) change the secured variable state, the long function checking the secured variable during its work. 
I'm pretty new in Python programming, so if that solution has a fundamental errors, like resources, timing, deadlocks problems , please response)).

Answer (score 0):

solving with the 'with' construct and merging solution from -

- [Timeout function if it takes too long to finish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281850/timeout-function-if-it-takes-too-long-to-finish)
- this thread which work better.

  ```
  import threading, time

  class Exception_TIMEOUT(Exception):
      pass

  class linwintimeout:

      def __init__(self, f, seconds=1.0, error_message='Timeout'):
          self.seconds = seconds
          self.thread = threading.Thread(target=f)
          self.thread.daemon = True
          self.error_message = error_message

      def handle_timeout(self):
          raise Exception_TIMEOUT(self.error_message)

      def __enter__(self):
          try:
              self.thread.start()
              self.thread.join(self.seconds)
          except Exception, te:
              raise te

      def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
          if self.thread.is_alive():
              return self.handle_timeout()

  def function():
      while True:
          print "keep printing ...", time.sleep(1)

  try:
      with linwintimeout(function, seconds=5.0, error_message='exceeded timeout of %s seconds' % 5.0):
          pass
  except Exception_TIMEOUT, e:
      print "  attention !! execeeded timeout, giving up ... %s " % e
  ```

Answer (score 0):

The [wrapt-timeout-decorator](https://pypi.org/project/wrapt-timeout-decorator/) library deserves its mention here:

```py
from wrapt_timeout_decorator import timeout

@timeout(10)
def function_with_timeout():
   ...
```

If the function does not finish in 10 seconds, an error is thrown.