# Python signal don't work even on Cygwin?

Tags: python, windows, signals

Python signal doesn't seem to work on Windows even if I run the python script inside Cygwin. I'm getting the `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute SIGALRM`

Is there a way to go around this on Windows. I'm just running the example at the end of http://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html

Comment: Is Python installed through Cygwin?

Comment: A signal is a Posix thing and most likely won't work on Windows. Cygwin is just translation layer and may not translate signal semantics to whatever Windows uses (but I'm not sure, I'd have to test it).

Comment: Indeed, installing Python through Cygwin (setup-x86_64.exe in my case) fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 6):

`SIGALRM` doesn't work in Windows. From the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html):

> On Windows, signal() can only be called with SIGABRT, SIGFPE, SIGILL, SIGINT, SIGSEGV, or SIGTERM. A ValueError will be raised in any other case.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8420422/python-windows-equivalent-of-sigalrm) addresses the topic of getting a `SIGALRM` equivalent in Windows. And [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6947065/right-way-to-run-some-code-with-timeout-in-python) is also similar.

Comment: Why did [this code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/366682/how-to-limit-execution-time-of-a-function-call-in-python/601168#601168) work on Python 2 on Windows (if I remember right) and break on Python 3 on Windows?  Maybe I was using a Python installed through cygwin...

Comment: Indeed, installing the Python that comes with Cygwin worked for me.