# In Oracle, how han I cancel broken connection?

Tags: python, multithreading, oracle, cx-oracle, oracle-call-interface

This code is in python but basically it's using `OCI` so should be reproducible in any other language:

```
import cx_Oracle as db
dsn = '(DESCRIPTION =(CONNECT_TIMEOUT=3)(RETRY_COUNT=1)(TRANSPORT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT=3)(ADDRESS_LIST =(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = SOME_HOST)(PORT = 1531)))(CONNECT_DATA =(SERVICE_NAME = SOME_NAME)))'
connect_string = "LOGIN/PASSWORD@%s" % dsn
conn = db.connect(connect_string)
conn.ping() # WILL HANG FOREVER!!!
```

If `SOME_HOST` is down, this will hang forever!

And it's not related to `OCIPing` - if I replace:

```
ping()
```

with:

```
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT 1 FROM DUAL') # HANG FOREVER AS WELL
```

This will hang as well.

I'm using **SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.3.0 Production on Wed Nov 6 12:17:09 2013**.

I tried wrapping this code in thread and waiting for same time than killing the thread but this doesn't work. This code creates a thread itself and it's impossible from python to kill it. Do you have any ideas how to recover?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is to use try/except/finally blocks but if part of your code is truly awaiting for a condition that would never be satisfied, what you need to do, is implement an internal timeout. There are numerous methods to do this. You can adapt the [solution to this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14652084/1309045) to your needs to get this done.

Hope this helps.

Comment: If you think about it, it will turn out you can implement internal timeout that is good enough for this situation.

Comment: Are you endorsing the answer, asking for more help, or rejecting the answer?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problems with interrupting `conn.ping()`.
Now I use next construction:

```python
from threading import Timer

pingTimeout = 10 # sec

# ...

def breakConnection():
    conn.cancel()
    connection = False

try:
    t = Timer(pingTimeout, breakConnection)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SELECT 1 FROM DUAL')
    t.close()
    cursor.close()
except Exception:
    connection = False

if not connection:
    print 'Trying to reconnect...'
    # ...
```

It's a dirty way, but it works.

And real way to check if a connection is usable is to execute the application statement you want run (I don't mean `SELECT 1 FROM DUAL`).
Then try retry, if you catch the exception.

Answer (score -1):

if you want close connection try

```
conn.close()
```

Comment: Yes, but how will this execute if it's hanging?