# Limit number of steps when matching a Regex in python

Tags: regex, python-3.x, user-input

Let's say you have a program that search in a user-provided text for a user-provided RegEx.

Using the [re module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html), how can I limit the number of steps the regex will make to prevent [catastrophic backtracking](https://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html).

Ideally, this SME should not hang:

```
regex = r"^(.*?,){11}P"

test_str = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21P" # Example stolen from the previous link.

matches = list(re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)) # This is an iterator so we consume it by casting to a list.
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11901328/how-to-timeout-function-in-python-timeout-less-than-a-second? Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492519/timeout-on-a-function-call ?

Comment: I know how to do it -- Thanks, but I would have very liked a max number of steps than a max number of seconds.

Comment: But yeah, I guess I'll use that to limit the execution time.

Comment: It is impossible to count those steps in `re`. There is no such functionality.

Comment: That's all I wanted to know, thanks. If you post that as an answer, I'll gladly accept it.