# Executing an asynchronous test in Python

Tags: python, unit-testing, sockets, simplehttpserver

I need to do the following test:

- send a GET request to a server (http://remote/...)
- wait for the server to send a POST request in response (http://local/...)
- parse the POST data and do some assertions

Selenium does not fit this case: it can't listen to connections, and I can send a GET without Selenium as well.

so, I make a unit test:

```
class MobiMoneyTestCase(TestCase):
def test_can_send_response(self):
    resp = requests.post('http://url/api/', data={'callback': 'http://localhost:8000'})

    class Handler(SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
        def do_GET(self):
            assert self.path == '...'

    httpd = SocketServer.ThreadingTCPServer(('localhost', 8000),Handler)
```

The test has to wait 5 seconds for the POST request and then fail if nothing happened. How can I merge these items in the test? If I put `sleep(5)` in the `test_can...`, the `httpd` handler does not reply until the countdown ends.

Comment: You are well beyond unittest teroritory and into integration testing. Use integration testing tools instead (Selenium, for example).

Comment: The other server also sends queries. I need a sort of HTTP server on my end too.

Answer (score -1):

Basically you want to timeout a process if it's too long ? You should check out the signal module in that case.

There is an neat implementation (with decorator) here : [Timeout function if it takes too long to finish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281850/timeout-function-if-it-takes-too-long-to-finish)

Comment: No. I need to do assert inside a spawned thread and raise AssertionError in the main function.