# Python timeout a function after some seconds

Tags: multithreading, python-2.7, timer

I need to time out a python function after specific time

```
def getDetails(id):
    Logic which takes more time
```

I need to timeout particular function after 5 seconds something like

```
timeout(getDetails(id),5)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2282656/2502012)

He defines a custom error that will be raised after a certain timeout period.