# How to force timeout functions in python, windows platform

Tags: python, timeout, urllib2

All I want to do is timeout a function if it does not return before that

It all started because urllib2 supports timeout for `urlopen`, but not for reading part
and my program hangs. Changing `defaulttimeout` for sockets does not work. Using `signal.sigalrm`
does not work. I can't switch to requests because then I will have to rewrite and test a lot more.

I DON'T want to make a thread run the function and then timeout the thread, I want to timeout the function. Any ideas how?

Answer (score 0):

I like to use David's class [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2282656/1272394) in my projects. I find it's very effective and I like that it provides a simple way to implement in existing code via a decorator. For example:

```
# Timeout after 30 seconds
@timeout(30)
def your_function():
    ...
```

*CAUTION*: This is **not** thread-safe! If you're using multithreading, the signal will get caught by a random thread. For single-threaded programs however, this is the easiest solution.

Comment: Unfortunately I am using windows, and signal.sigalrm is not supported by windows. The code you pointed at uses signal.sigalrm

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be done in windows without signal and it will also work in other os as well. This is using thread but not to run the function but to raise a signal for timeout. The logic is to create a new thread and wait for a given time and raise an exception using _thread(in python3 and thread in python2). This exception will be thrown in the main thread and the with block will get exit if any exception occurs.

```
import threading
import _thread   # import thread in python2
class timeout():
  def __init__(self, time):
    self.time= time
    self.exit=False

  def __enter__(self):
    threading.Thread(target=self.callme).start()

  def callme(self):
    time.sleep(self.time)
    if self.exit==False:
       _thread.interrupt_main()  # use thread instead of _thread in python2
  def __exit__(self, a, b, c):
       self.exit=True
```

Usuage Example :-

```
with timeout(2):
    func()
```

The program in the with block should exit within 2 seconds otherise it will be exited after 2 seconds.

Comment: do not use this anywhere near your code, i dont think this is thread safe, the whole program will exit in my case