# Django Management - Stop running task

Tags: python, django, unix

I have a script that I'm building an interface for so people can execute after uploading a CSV file. Is there a way to call a command using:

```
management.call_command()
```

But then stop the running script programatically? This would be if the script takes too long.

Any help is much appreciated.

Zee

Comment: possible duplicate of [Timeout on a Python function call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492519/timeout-on-a-python-function-call)

Comment: I should probably clarify. What I meant was is there a way to stop the script manually? Not necessarily through a timeout.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/2282656/3951758.
Also you can use [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) to kill any process at certain time.