# How can I do a non-blocking read with SMBus?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, nonblocking

I have this simple code:

```
import smbus

i2c = smbus.SMBus(1)

i2c.read_byte(0x20)
```

However, I'd like to make the read function non-blocking, or at least have a short timeout (i.e ~100 MS). The reason for this is I'm using a second board to tell if another I2C device gets frozen. I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281850/timeout-function-if-it-takes-too-long-to-finish), but I think that stopping this function mid-operation would cause the I2C connection to be unstable. Is there any way to set a short timeout for this function?