# How can I exit a Python3 script after 5 minutes

Tags: python, unix, python-3.x

I have a script that was copying data from SD card. Due to the huge amount of files/filesize, this might take a longer period of time than expected. I would like to exit this script after 5 minutes. How can I do so?

Comment: You could try setting an alarm signal to go off in 5 minutes and have the alarm signal handler exit the process.

Comment: Could you possible to post a sample answer so I can check and select as an answer.

Comment: Windows or Unix? If Unix: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22348885/47351

Comment: Unix, sorry to be new in python is this `with timeout(seconds=300):` will solve my problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's hard to verify that this will work without any example code, but you could try something like this, using the [signal module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html):

At the beginning of your code, define a handler for the alarm signal.

```
import signal

def handler(signum, frame):
    print 'Times up! Exiting..."
    exit(0)
```

Before you start the long process, add a line like this to your code:

```
#Install signal handler
signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, handler)

#Set alarm for 5 minutes
signal.alarm(300)
```

In 5 minutes, your program will receive the alarm signal, which will call the handler, which will exit. You can also do other things in the handler if you want.

Answer (score 1):

Here, the threading module comes in handily:

```
import threading

def eternity(): # your method goes here
    while True:
        pass

t=threading.Thread(target=eternity) # create a thread running your function
t.start()                           # let it run using start (not run!)
t.join(3)                           # join it, with your timeout in seconds
```