# How can I stop a python script on a batch file

Tags: python, batch-file, cmd

I want to start a python script and then automatically close that script after 2 minutes, run another command, and keep doing the same thing again like this (loop) forever :

```
Cd c:/location.of.script/
pythonscript.py
Stop (like ctrl+c) pythonscript.py after 120s
Del -f cookies.file
.
.
.
```

Is this even possible with a batch file on windows 10?  If so, can someone please help me with this?

I’ve been looking everywhere but found nothing except the `exit()` command which stops the script from inside - this isn’t what I want to do.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2888851/how-to-stop-process-from-bat-file + https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1672338/how-to-sleep-for-five-seconds-in-a-batch-file-cmd + https://stackoverflow.com/questions/893203/bat-files-nonblocking-run-launch are the tools you need.

Comment: Easier to do with PowerShell? Also might be a better question for https://superuser.com/

Comment: @tim how can I make it easier with powershell ?

Answer (score 0):

You can change your python script to exit after 2 minutes, and you could batch file that has a while loop that runs forever and run the python script then deletes the cookie.file, I don't know if that's exactly what you want, but you can do it by putting a timer in your python script.

You can make a separate thread that keeps track of the time and terminates the code after some time.

An example of such a code could be:

```
import threading

def eternity(): # your method goes here
    while True:
        pass

t=threading.Thread(target=eternity) # create a thread running your function
t.start()                           # let it run using start (not run!)
t.join(3)                           # join it, with your timeout in seconds
```

And this code is copied from https://stackoverflow.com/a/30186772/4561068

Comment: The code have to be put inside the python script right ? So it need to be on the start of that script right ? Because I suck at python and I don’t really want to touch that code I prefer if there is a way to do it from batch file or powershell as another user suggested.