# set timeout seconds for a function during runtime python

Tags: python, python-2.7, timeout, settimeout

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2282656/5203702) solution.

I am trying to set timeout seconds to my function `during runtime`, which gives me flexibility to pass different `timeout seconds` without even opening a script.(test.py)

timeout.py

```
from functools import wraps
import errno
import os
import signal


class TimeoutError(Exception):
    pass


def timeout(seconds=60, error_message=(os.strerror(errno.ETIMEDOUT)).upper()):
    def decorator(func):
        def _handle_timeout(signum, frame):
            raise TimeoutError(error_message)

        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, _handle_timeout)
            #print "Timeout seconds =: " , seconds
            signal.alarm(seconds)
            try:
                result = func(*args, **kwargs)
            finally:
                signal.alarm(0)
            return result

       return wraps(func)(wrapper)
   return decorator
```

main.py (just takes whatever parameter passed during runtime)

```
import test
if __name__ == '__main__':
    args1=sys.argv[1]
    args2=sys.argv[2]
    time_sec = sys.argv[3] 

    test.func(args1,arg2,time_sec)
```

test.py

```
from timeout import timeout
from timeout import TimeoutError

#@timeout(30)
@timeout()      #<--here i want to pass timeout_sec
def func(args1,args2,timeout_sec):
     #do something
```

To run this:

```
 python main.py abc abc 45   #this overrids seconds from timeout.py
```

In test.py `timeout()` or `timeout(30)` will work, but is there any way to make it dynamic and get the seconds passed as "arg3" in `@timeout(arg3)`

Is there any way i can achieve this?

Comment: Why not apply the decorator the old-fashioned way? `timeout.timeout(time_sec)(test.func)(args1, arg2)`

Comment: @jonrsharpe    That's not working. Getting an error `TypeError: func() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)`

Comment: Presumably because you still have the now-redundant `timeout_sec` argument in its definition.

Comment: @jonrsharpe  Yes did a silly mistake. Your solution works. Thanks.