# How to specify test timeout for python unittest?

Tags: python, unit-testing, timeout

I'm using `python` framework `unittest`. Is it possible to specify by framework's abilities a timeout for test? If no, is it possible to specify gracefully a `timeout` for all tests and for some separated tests a private value for each one?
I want to define a `global timeout` for all tests (they will use it by default) and a timeout for some test that can take a long time.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

As far as I know [`unittest`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/unittest.html) does not contain any support for tests timeout.

You can try [`timeout-decorator`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/timeout-decorator) library from PyPI. Apply the decorator on individual tests to make them terminate if they take too long:

```
import timeout_decorator

class TestCaseWithTimeouts(unittest.TestCase):

    # ... whatever ...

    @timeout_decorator.timeout(LOCAL_TIMEOUT)
    def test_that_can_take_too_long(self):
        sleep(float('inf'))

    # ... whatever else ...
```

To create a global timeout, you can replace call

```
unittest.main()
```

with

```
timeout_decorator.timeout(GLOBAL_TIMEOUT)(unittest.main)()
```

Comment: Interesting. I'm not using `unittest.main()`, but I hope I can adopt `decorator` for my case. But my tests are not going in single thread...

Comment: @Jury Check the "Multithreading" section in [`timeout-decorator` reference](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/timeout-decorator) - you just need to use `timeout_decorator.timeout(TIMEOUT, use_signals=False)` in multi-threaded environment.

Comment: Yes, I've seen it. I'll try.

Comment: I don't know what is going on, but `use_signals=False` doesn't work for me, but with signals it looks working. As I found, this module makes hook to call `_Timeout.__call__` instead of testmethod directly. The problem is in fact that `self` of testmethod is lost (replaced) by `self` of `_Timeout`. When called, `testmethod` doesn't have any `self` and it fails. I don't know what is going on and how to fix it. Trick with global timeout doesn't work too.

Comment: Unfortunately, neither it works in my case with the async websockets tests in Python 3.

Comment: @Jury I actually make it works. Only by using decorator with exception:
`@timeout_decorator.timeout(TIMEOUT, timeout_exception=StopIteration)`. You'll need to put this decorator on all potential stacked tests. In my case it is in tests related to async/websocket

Comment: This is a lovely approach - thanks for sharing!

Decorating individual classes works for me, but wrapping unittest.main does not.

I'm using Python 3.7.7 on MacOS 15 (Catalina.)

Comment: This works for my tests that hang in Python code, but not when they get lost during a call to an external C++ library. I tried with and without *use_signals*. Any suggestions?

Comment: @AdamWildavsky I'm afraid there's too much that can happen in C++ code. You could try running your entire test suite in a subprocess with parent process in charge of timeout - that's kinda a sledgehammer approach, but it's the best I can offer off the top of my head. Perhaps better to frame it as a separate question as it deserves to be treated as such IMHO.

Answer (score 14):

I built a `unittest` timeout solution using context managers (the `with` keyowrd), [based on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281850/timeout-function-if-it-takes-too-long-to-finish/2282656).

This approach also uses `signal`, so it might only be valid on *nix systems (I've only run it in my Ubuntu 16.04 environment).

1. Import signal, add a `TestTimeout` exception:

```py
import signal

...

class TestTimeout(Exception):
    pass
```

2. Define class `test_timeout`, which will handle the `with` blocks:

```py
class test_timeout:
  def __init__(self, seconds, error_message=None):
    if error_message is None:
      error_message = 'test timed out after {}s.'.format(seconds)
    self.seconds = seconds
    self.error_message = error_message

  def handle_timeout(self, signum, frame):
    raise TestTimeout(self.error_message)

  def __enter__(self):
    signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, self.handle_timeout)
    signal.alarm(self.seconds)

  def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
    signal.alarm(0)
```

3. Embed `with test_timeout()` blocks in your unit tests:

```py
def test_foo(self):
  with test_timeout(5):  # test has 5 seconds to complete
    ... foo unit test code ...
```

With this approach, tests that time out will result in an error due to the `raise TestTimeout` exception.

Optionally, you could wrap the `with test_timeout()` block in a `try: except TestTimeout:` block, and handle the exception with more granularity (skip a test instead of error for example).

Comment: This is a great option which doesn't need external dependencies. I did a slight variation of this by setting up/clearing the alarm in setUp() and tearDown() so it applies to all tests in a test case. It would probably be wise to also disable the alarm in the __exit__ or tearDown too: signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, signal.SIG_DFL)