# Nestable timeout decorator? (i.e. timeout decorated func calling timeout decorated func)

Tags: python, timeout, decorator

I need a decorator (or something that is functionally equivalent) that allows the code below to work as expected:

```
@timeout(1)
def outer():
    inner()

@timeout(5)
def inner():
    time.sleep(3)
    print("Should never be printed if you call outer()")

outer()
# The outer timeout is ignored and "property" finishes
```

The code seems pointless, but in reality, `outer` calls multiple functions that take uncertain amount of time, some of which have their own timeout.

I tried [timeout-decorator](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/timeout-decorator) and [two SO answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281850/timeout-function-if-it-takes-too-long-to-finish), but none works.

Comment: What was the problem with timeout-decorator?

Comment: Everything I listed has the same outcome: the outer timeout is ignored.

Comment: There seems to be half a dozen timeout implementations on [pypi](http://pypi.python.org). One challenge is that signal based timeouts don't work outside of python's main thread. If timeout-decorator doesn't work for you, that may be the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this:

```
def timeout(timeout, raise_exc=True):
    """
    raise_exc - if exception should be raised on timeout 
                or exception inside decorated func.
                Otherwise None will be returned.
    """
    def decorator(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            res = None
            exc = None
            def _run():
                nonlocal res
                nonlocal exc
                try:
                    res = func(*args, **kwargs)
                except Exception as e:
                    exc = e
            t = threading.Thread(target=_run)
            t.daemon = True
            t.start()
            t.join(timeout=timeout)
            if raise_exc and t.is_alive():
                raise TimeoutError()
            elif raise_exc and (exc is not None):
                raise exc
            else:
                return res
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

Examples:

```
@timeout(0.5, raise_exc=False)
def outer():
    return inner()

@timeout(2)
def inner():
    time.sleep(1)
    return "Shouldn't be printed"

print(outer())  # None
```

and

```
@timeout(2, raise_exc=False)
def outer():
    return inner()

@timeout(2)
def inner():
    time.sleep(1)
    return "Should be printed"

print(outer())  # Should be printed
```

Note, that your task can be solved only with threads or processes, but this may lead to some non-obvious [problems](https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/2zkczi/what_are_the_problems_with_threads_in_python/). I recommend you to think if your task can be solved without it. In most cases you can split your code to parts and check for timeout after each. Something like this:

```
def outer(arg, timeout=None):
    t = Timeout(timeout)
    # some operation:
    time.sleep(1)
    if t.is_timeout: return None
    # use time left as subfunction's timeout:
    return inner(arg, timeout=t.time_left)
```

Comment: `if raise_exc and t.is_alive()` is buggy. `t.is_alive()` won't be evaluated if `raise_exec` is `False` and you `return res` without confirming thtat thread has ended. what happens to the started non-main thread when you `raise TimeoutError()` in the main thread? It seems the started thread is not ending, keep running? Actually, how it works?

Comment: `t.is_alive()` shouldn't be checked if `raise_exc == False`: in that case we just return `None`, see timer's docstring. When we raise `TimeoutError()` started thread finished: it provided by `t.join(timeout=timeout)` line.

Comment: `t.join(timeout=timeout)` can return before the thread finishes. That's why we have to check with `t.is_alive()`. Anyhow the started thread keeps running after `raise TimeoutError()` if it's a long running task.

Comment: @NizamMohamed, that's true, thread keeps running, but we shouldn't worry about it as soon as our main main thread is not blocked. That's how this timeout decorator works. Trying to kill started thread manually is bad idea: what if it holds critical resources? Only way I see to finish it is to allow finish properly.

Comment: what happens if the non-main threads raises exception inside the thread? How can we make sure main thread is not blocked?

Comment: @NizamMohamed main thread shouldn't be blocked because in that case `join` just finish, doesn't it? But thanks for asking about exceptions: I updated function to handle exception inside non-main thread and pass it to main thread if raise_exc.

Comment: you can't know if timeout has occurred or thread finished without checking `is_alive`. The OP wanted to abort the operation if not finished within some time constraint. But here the operation keeps going.

Comment: hmm... you guys' discussions are _a bit_ beyond my level... I'll search and check, and get back...

Comment: @akai, he is right that task "finished" by timeout still running in background thread. But I don't see any alternative to it. Besides it's hard to send arbitrary exception to another thread, it can easily break code (see answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/325528/1113207 ). I still recommend you to leave idea of timeout decorator, but instead of this to check time manually after some operations (see the end of answer).

Comment: All right, I think I understand basically. Thanks for your discussions, they were very helpful. I will use one of the two (three) suggested solutions depending on my cases.

Answer (score 2):

The `timeout` function uses `threading.Timer` to set the timer and `thread.interrupt_main` to interrupt the main thread.

```
from thread import interrupt_main
from threading import Timer
from time import time, sleep

def timeout(secs):
    def wrapper(func):
        timer = Timer(secs, interrupt_main)
        def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
            timer.start()
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return decorated
    return wrapper            

@timeout(1)
def outer():
    inner()

@timeout(5)
def inner():
    sleep(3)
    print("Should never be printed if you call outer()")

try:
    outer()
except:
    print('timed out')
```