# Skip loop if a function is taking too long?

Tags: python, numpy

I have Python code which is taking too long, and I would like to stop and skip execution of this function if it takes longer than a few seconds.

For example, the function I want to time is:

```
batch_xs, batch_ys = train_loadbatch_from_lists(batch_size)
```

In some instances this function call takes too long, and I would like to cancel it.

I'm looking for something like this:

```
if time for batch_xs, batch_ys = train_loadbatch_from_lists(batch_size) > 20 seconds:
    then skip
```

with reference to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281850/timeout-function-if-it-takes-too-long-to-finish).

I would like to know how I would call the function again if timeout occurs.

For instance

```
@timeout(15)
def abcd(hello):
#some def
```

I would like to call the function again if it crosses the timer.

Comment: There are some ideas here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281850/timeout-function-if-it-takes-too-long-to-finish

Comment: Yeah I went through it. But I'm not sure I know How to use it well.
So If I have @timeout(15) defined before a function definition and if the error occurs I would like to call it again. Do u know how this can be done ?

Comment: I really would not recommend using signals. They seem like a decent solution but have all sorts of weird side effects, corner cases etc and can end up causing more problems than they solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call a function in the same thread, it will normally not return until complete.  The function you call really has to be designed to be interruptible in the first place. There are many ways to achieve this, with varying degrees of complexity and generality.

Probably the simplest way is to pass the time limit to your function, and process the work in small chunks. After each chunk is processed, check if the elapsed time exceeds the timeout and if so, bail early.

The following example illustrates this idea, with the work taking a random amount of time per chunk which will sometimes complete and sometimes time out:

```
import time
import random
import datetime

class TimeoutException(Exception):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Exception.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

def busy_work():

    # Pretend to do something useful
    time.sleep(random.uniform(0.3, 0.6))

def train_loadbatch_from_lists(batch_size, timeout_sec):

    time_start = datetime.datetime.now()
    batch_xs = []
    batch_ys = []

    for i in range(0, batch_size+1):
        busy_work()
        batch_xs.append(i)
        batch_ys.append(i)

        time_elapsed = datetime.datetime.now() - time_start
        print 'Elapsed:', time_elapsed
        if time_elapsed > timeout_sec:
            raise TimeoutException()

    return batch_xs, batch_ys

def main():

    timeout_sec = datetime.timedelta(seconds=5)
    batch_size = 10
    try:
        print 'Processing batch'
        batch_xs, batch_ys = train_loadbatch_from_lists(batch_size, timeout_sec)
        print 'Completed successfully'
        print batch_xs, batch_ys
    except TimeoutException, e:
        print 'Timeout after processing N records'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Another way to achieve this is to run the worker function in a separate thread, and use an `Event` to allow the caller to signal the worker function should terminate early.

Some posts (such as the linked one above) suggest using signals, but unfortunately signals can cause additional complications, and so is not recommended.