# How to print something every minute that the raw_input is not entered?

Tags: python-2.7, loops, raw-input

I was wondering if anyone could tell me if there is a way in python 2.7 to have the program print something every minute that the `raw_input` isn't entered. 
For example:

```
if raw_input == "stop loop":
    break
```

But while nothing is entered in the `raw_input` it reprints `"enter something"` every minute that passes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following example (create a file that contains the follwing code and run it with `python` command):

```
from functools import wraps
import errno
import os
import signal


class TimeoutError(Exception):
    pass


def timeout(seconds=10, error_message=os.strerror(errno.ETIME)):
    def decorator(func):
        def _handle_timeout(signum, frame):
            raise TimeoutError(error_message)

        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, _handle_timeout)
            signal.alarm(seconds)
            try:
                result = func(*args, **kwargs)
            finally:
                signal.alarm(0)
            return result

        return wraps(func)(wrapper)

    return decorator


@timeout(60)
def print_something():
    return raw_input('Enter something: \n')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    data = ""
    while data != "stop loop":
        try:
            data = print_something()
        except TimeoutError:
            continue
```

My answer is based on the accepted answer for this SO question [Timeout function if it takes too long to finish](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2282656/4575071)

Comment: I am running this and it does the job but doesn't repeat if nothing is entered it only repeats once something is entered in "data" am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It should work, did you wait for 60 seconds and nothing happened?

Comment: Thank you very much @ettanany this works. I was just wondering if you could explain how the decorator function works and what it exactly does purely out of curiosity so I can use it if need be.

Comment: The decorator is used to change the function behavior. You may need to take a look at some tutorial about decorators in Python, it is an important feature.