# How to set a timeout for a pymysql query

Tags: pymysql

I have a situation where a pymysql query may take longer than the amount of time allowed. Ideally, the call aborts with an exception after a set number of seconds or mills, so it can be reported and move forward.

Is there a way to limit the amount of time a query can execute for a given session/connection?

Answer (score 0):

based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22348885/6779252) answer you can do:

```
with timeout(seconds=3):
    cursor.execute('your sql query')
```