# urllib.request.urlopen timeout without internet

Tags: python, python-3.x, request, urllib, urlopen

`urllib.request.urlopen` has a `timeout` option. However, when my internet is down that option does not seem to work.

```
import urllib
urllib.request.urlopen(url, timeout=1)
```

Hangs and eventually gives

```
URLError: <urlopen error [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution>
```

How can I impose a timeout when my internet is down?

Answer (score 2):

That isn't trivial. You have a DNS timeout as your system cannot figure out what to do with the URL given. However, this is out of control of python as noted by David Murray here: https://bugs.python.org/issue22889

You may want to go for this custom timeout implementation: [Timeout function if it takes too long to finish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281850/timeout-function-if-it-takes-too-long-to-finish/22348885#22348885)

Comment: Thank you for the links. It seems there isn't really a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can read this [post](https://vorpus.org/blog/timeouts-and-cancellation-for-humans). It explains well that currently `timeout` is a very obscure concept. Even in `requests` which claims "For human", `timeout` is not really for human.

In your case, name resolution is a pre-process before http connection, but `timeout` only works for http(s) and ftp connection.

To obtain a consistent behavior of `timeout`, I guess the best way is to use thread. Or you can use `signal.alarm` but it only works on UNIX system.