# location.getLocation() is taking too long on a real android device. Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, location

I'm having a problem when trying to get the user location using `location.getLocation()` on a real device, now **it works perfectly on the emulator and super fast** but **on a real device it's slow**, I don't know why is that.

the plugin version is `^3.0.2`.

anybody has any idea about what's going on here.

Comment: have you checked permission and turn on location in the device?

Comment: @JavadDehban oh yeah, permissions and everything else is ok, the real device is getting the location eventually, the problem is that it's taking too long to do that

Comment: Facing Same issue

Comment: Posted a hacky solution below :)

Comment: any luck you get this fast ... as i need to stamp location on every photo.. but getting location is taking 2 second every time

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue, but I noticed something.

**OBSERVATION 1**
Location is off, now I click button to fetch location. It asks me to turn on Location, I turn it on, It takes forever to `await location.getLocation();` Execution never reaches next line of code.

**OBSERVATION 2**
Location is ON, now I click button to fetch location. It doesnot ask to turn on location because it is already on, Guess WHAT, it gets user location in under 3-4 seconds

### HOW TO DEAL WITH OBSERVATION 1?

**SOLUTION**

```dart
_locationData = await Future.any([
  location.getLocation(),
  Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5), () => null),
]);
if (_locationData == null) {
  _locationData = await location.getLocation();
}
```

**EXPLANATION**

I basically kept a timeout of 5 Seconds, if i donot get location in 5 seconds, I discard it returning `null` & then I hit it again!! & it worked

I have observed this issue in several apps. It is just that the `getLocation()` function works well if location is already turned on.. this should not happen ideally, there must be some deep down issue with plugin or device hardware.

Hope this helps!

PS : This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/66108572/7475099 helped me in forming above solution.

Comment: 3 to 4 second is also a huge time, any finding on this

Answer (score 2):

There is a similar issue for iOS devices.

See [this comment](https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter-geolocator/issues/320#issuecomment-983395591) for more information.

Not found a good solution for this yet.

Seems it might be best to use `getLastKnownPosition()`, but not sure how well that works if it is the first time you are pulling the location.