# How to check if a function doesn't return a value (API)

Tags: python, api, try-catch, sleep

I'm using an API to receive data every one second using a structure like this:

```
from time import sleep
try:
    data = API(options)
except:
    sleep(0.5)
```

The whole process is in a bigger loop for repeating that every one second. Sometimes this API returns an error so this structure can handle this issue. But sometimes I think it doesn't return any value for a long time, so this will stop the code, and I need to run the API function again. How can I handle this in my code?

Comment: Is there any indication that no value is returned from the API after a long time? For example, does the API return some sort of Request Timeout exception?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Timeout function if it takes too long to finish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281850/timeout-function-if-it-takes-too-long-to-finish)

Comment: @TerryA No. It will be stopped for a long time. When I press CTL+C in the IPython, it shows that it's in the exception part and after that, continue the process again.

Comment: Did you check if this API allows you to set a specific timeout value?

Comment: @AuroraWang Yes. I didn't find anything.