# Timeout if function takes too long to print to stdout

Tags: python-3.x

Building upon this previous question: [Timeout function if it takes too long to finish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281850/timeout-function-if-it-takes-too-long-to-finish),
I have to use a closed-source library that doesn't use timeouts in its calls to `requests` (and doesn't accept a timeout parameter).
The function I'm calling outputs directly to `stdout`.

Instead of monkey-patching the library, I'd like to wrap the function call in such a way that `stdout` is monitored for changes. If stdout doesn't receive an input within X seconds, a `TimeoutError` is raised.

How do I go about doing this?