# Detect where are exceptions caught

Tags: python, exception, timeout, signals, sympy

I'm using the SymPy library to do some formal math computation. Sometimes, some mathematical expressions are very slow to compute, and SymPy never returns. So I implemented a TimeOut exception (like in the best answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281850/timeout-function-if-it-takes-too-long-to-finish) around my functions that are slow to return, so that I can catch too long expressions and skip them.

It works in 99% of cases, but in some very rare cases, the exception is not caught by Python, and the code just stays stuck on a very long expression, and never returns.

I first noticed that when I replace the `Exception` type of my `TimeoutException` by a `BaseException`, it works better, i.e. the TimeoutException is now catched in 99.9% of cases.

Then I noticed that in SymPy there are a few parts of the code ignoring all exceptions, with for instance: `except BaseException` or `except:`:
https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/master/sympy/core/basic.py#L1800
https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/master/sympy/solvers/solveset.py#L530
I tried to fix these instances, but my code still freezes every once in a while, and I cant figure out why.

Is there a way in Python to detect where an exception is catched in the code? I would like to see something like "TimeoutException has been catched in FILE at line XXX" so that I can fix the problematic `try/except` that ignore the Timeout. Or I'm wondering whether I could bypass the too generic `except:` in SymPy?

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if logging module would be able to help to determine the issue.

Try something like this:

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger('name')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
handle = logging.FileHandler(filename='logs.log', encoding='utf-8', mode='w')
handle.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s:%(levelname)s:%(name)s: %(message)s'))
logger.addHandler(handle)
```