# Pytest assert for timeout?

Tags: python, pytest

Is there a way to assert that a Pytest test case has failed due to a pytest timeout? I want to run a longevity test that I expect to run without issue, until a pytest timeout is encountered. I annotate the test with @pytest.mark.timeout(6000)to override the default pytest timeout, and when the 6000 second timeout is encountered, the test fails with `E       Failed: Timeout >6000.0s`.

I've tried adding `with pytest.raises(pytest.TimeoutExpired)` to my test to catch the eventual timeout, but that doesn't seem to do the trick. Is there a way to properly catch the timeout raised by pytest?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, the [pytest-timeout plugin](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-timeout/), which provides the `@pytest.mark.timeout` marker, does not offer the means to catch the timeout ([source](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-timeout/blob/e1c17ed8ac1937403d9dbeba972de7650704d381/pytest_timeout.py) for reference).

You may find more luck using a library that offers timeout functionality as a context manager, such as the one from [Thomas Ahle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/205521/thomas-ahle)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22348885/148585)

```
import signal

class Timeout:
    def __init__(self, seconds=1, error_message='Timeout'):
        self.seconds = seconds
        self.error_message = error_message
    def handle_timeout(self, signum, frame):
        raise TimeoutError(self.error_message)
    def __enter__(self):
        signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, self.handle_timeout)
        signal.alarm(self.seconds)
    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        signal.alarm(0)

def test_it_doesnt_succeed():
    try:
        with Timeout(seconds=6):
            do_the_thing()
    except TimeoutError:
        pass
    else:
        raise AssertionError('Expected the thing to timeout!')
```

Comment: To add, it does not appear that there are currently any plans to add an exception feature per [closed issue](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-timeout/issues/38).