# Timeout function with clean exit

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, threadpool

I'm trying to implement something like this in python:

```
obj = MyObj()
obj.run_task()

# if run_task() takes more than 10 seconds.
obj.clean_exit() # contains logic to exit the task cleanly
```

`MyObj` or `run_task()` cannot contain the timing logic. It has to be external. How do I do this in python ? I'm looking for something similar to this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492519/timeout-on-a-function-call) , but do not want to terminate the task - just need to call the clean_exit() method after 10 seconds. I'm a noob in python.

Comment: Simply replace the `raise` with your logic in the `handler` function I believe will do the trick...

Comment: [This is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281850/timeout-function-if-it-takes-too-long-to-finish?noredirect=1&lq=1) a bit of a different take on the same method