# Interrupt shell process in python if it's taking too long

Tags: python, shell, scripting

I'm scripting in `python`.
I need to write to disk, and run some shell scripts.
However, depending on the the input, these may take a long time, and I want to kill them if they take too long.
I want something like:

```py
def run_once(input_text):
    with open("temp.file", "w") as f:
        f.write(input_text)
    os.system("./synthesize.sh temp.tsl")

for single in many:
    if(takes_more_than_60_seconds(run_once(input_text)):
        kill(process)
        print("Process killed since it took too long. Moving to the next job.")
```

Comment: This thread has a really good example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281850/timeout-function-if-it-takes-too-long-to-finish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `os.system`, try `subprocess.run` and use the `timeout` option:

```py
# file: sleepy.py
import time
time.sleep(10)
```

```py
# file: monitor.py
import subprocess
import shlex

try:
    subprocess.run(shlex.split("python sleepy.py"), timeout=5)
except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
    print("Timed out")
```

When you run `python monitor.py`, it blocks until the timeout is reached.