# Libcloud Storage - How to specify the requests timeouts?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, storage, libcloud

I use the [Libcloud 3.3.1](https://libcloud.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) python library to download objects from an Openstack swift provider.

When using the requests package, one can specify the [connect and read timeouts](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced/#timeouts) to avoid getting stuck when retrieving a file.

Is it posssible to define such timeouts in the Libcloud package?
I know I can give a [timeout in the connection arguments](https://libcloud.readthedocs.io/en/stable/apidocs/libcloud.common.html#libcloud.common.base.Connection) but that doesn't seem to do what I want (it is a retry timeout).

I also have been thinking about using the signal package and [this reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2282656/4187749), but once again this is not exactly what I want and I would like to avoid doing such things.

Comment: looks like you can't without modifying the libcloud library. It internally uses `requests`, but doesn't specify a timeout when calling `requests.Session().request` in the `LibCloudConnection` class [(see `libcloud.http.LibcloudConnection.request`)](https://github.com/apache/libcloud/blob/trunk/libcloud/http.py#L220)

Comment: @rémi-chauvenne can you provide the code for which you are creating the connection parameter? As per your reference you are showing that you use [libcloud.common.base.Connection](https://libcloud.readthedocs.io/en/stable/apidocs/libcloud.common.html#libcloud.common.base.Connection) whereas, the openshift connection object if used with `LibcloudConnection` can have the timeout of requests