# How to interrupt function by signal?

Tags: python, signals, decorator

I want to code decorator which interrupt function after 1 sec, so:

```
@timer
def func():
    sleep(0.1)
```

is `OK`, but

```
@timer
def func():
    sleep(1.1)
```

is `RunTimeError`.

But i dont understand where in decorator i should code signal. maybe there are similar examples?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Timeout function if it takes too long to finish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281850/timeout-function-if-it-takes-too-long-to-finish)