# Is it possible to cancel an exec() in python after 5 seconds

Tags: python, multithreading, time, eval

I am working on a python script that runs small user generated scripts. There is a problem though when a user submits a script that infinitely loops. I was wondering if it would be possible to stop an exec() after 5 seconds of running.

```
x = exec(user_code)
 delay(5)
 x.cancel()
```

something like this ^

So far I tried using threading but the results were mixed. I threaded a function called main which would run their code through exec then I would delete the thread after 5 seconds but it was buggy.

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: You might be able to do something with multiple threads, where the second thread kills the first one.

Comment: Or possibly https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281850/timeout-function-if-it-takes-too-long-to-finish

Comment: @larsks I checked out that article but it does not focus on the python exec() function

Comment: The second link has solutions for *arbitrary* functions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could use multiprocessing:

```
import multiprocessing
import time

def exec(n):
    for i in range(10000 * n):
        print("Whatever") #Your code

if __name__ == '__main__':
    process = multiprocessing.Process(target=exec, name="Exec", args=(10,))
    process.start()
    time.sleep(1) #How much to wait
    process.terminate()
    process.join()
```

Comment: this is probably a reasonable solution, but don't name the function `exec`, that shadows the built-in `exec` (btw, I did not downvote)