# How to pass a variable to an exception when raised and retrieve it when excepted?

Tags: python, exception

Right now I just have a blank exception class. I was wondering how I can give it a variable when it gets raised and then retrieve that variable when I handle it in the try...except.

```
class ExampleException (Exception):
    pass
```

Comment: [Nice example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1319675/201665) if you want to retain the default message behavior.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Give its constructor an argument, store that as an attribute, then retrieve it in the `except` clause:

```
class FooException(Exception):
    def __init__(self, foo):
        self.foo = foo

try:
    raise FooException("Foo!")
except FooException as e:
    print e.foo
```

Answer (score -3):

You can do this.

```
try:
    ex = ExampleException()
    ex.my_variable= "some value"
    raise ex
except ExampleException, e:
    print( e.my_variable )
```

Works fine.

Comment: Although this work, it's not generally a good practice to set object attributes like this.  The accepted answer approach of doing this inside `__init__` is better.