# Pass variable to an exception?

Tags: python, exception

I am trying to learn Python and I want to know if it is possible to pass a variable to an `Exception`? This is the code I have:

```
try:
    staffId = int(row['staffId'])
    openingSalary = int(row['initialSalary'])
    monthsWorked = float(row['monthsWorked'])
except CutomException:
    pass

class CustomException(ValueError): # raised if data conversion fails
    def __init__(self):
        print("There was a problem converting data")
```

I want to pass `staffId` to the exception so that I can print something like:

print("There was a problem converting data for staff Id: ", staffId)

I tried this with no success: [How to pass a variable to an exception when raised and retrieve it when excepted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6626816/how-to-pass-a-variable-to-an-exception-when-raised-and-retrieve-it-when-excepted)

Comment: The answer to the question you linked will do what you're looking for (e.g., call `raise CustomException` inside of your `try` block)

Comment: Wouldn't it raise CustomException even of there are no errors in the try block?

Comment: I provided an answer below to illustrate it further. In short, you need to conditionalize `raise` the `CustomException` to avoid raising the exception every time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The caller of the exception, e.g. the one that `raise` exception will have to pass an argument to the constructor.

```
class CustomException(ValueError): # raised if data conversion fails
    def __init__(self, message):
        self.message = message;
        print("There was a problem converting data")


try:
    try:
        staffId = int(row['staffId'])
        openingSalary = int(row['initialSalary'])
        monthsWorked = float(row['monthsWorked'])
    except ValueError as e:
        raise CustomException(e);
except CustomException:
    pass
```

Comment: How do I do that in a try...except statement? In my example if the information provided is incorrect, let's say that you pass a string to staffId then the exception gets raised automatically. At least that is how I understand it.

Comment: @komodo you can do it with nested exceptions, just pass

Comment: Curious, is `Cutom` intended to differ from `Custom`?

Answer (score 1):

The custom exception will need to be `raise`'d conditionally by the `try` block to include the `staffId` variable. As an example, when the `staffId` is a `str` and not an `int`.

```
try:
    # conditionalize a scenario where you'd want to raise an error
    #  (e.g. the variable is a string)
    if type(staffId) is str:
        raise CustomException(staffId)
    else:
        staffId = int(row['staffId'])
        openingSalary = int(row['initialSalary'])
        monthsWorked = float(row['monthsWorked'])
except CutomException:
    pass

class CustomException(ValueError): # raised if data conversion fails
    def __init__(self, id):
        print("There was a problem converting data %s" % id)
```

Comment: The problem is that all the info in row are strings because they come from a csv file that was extracted to a dictionary. Therefore, I can't check if staffId is a string because I already know it is. Good idea though;)

Comment: @komodo I was using that as a condition from your comment to the other answer. In any event, I think the other answer has what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should handle the exception in the except block and not inside the exception class.

```
try:
    raise CustomException(foo)
except CutomException as e:
    print(e.args)
    handle_exception()

class CustomException(Exception):
    def __init__(self, foo):
        super().__init__(foo, bar)
```