# How to make a custom exception class with multiple init args pickleable

Tags: python, exception, serialization

Why does my custom Exception class below not serialize/unserialize correctly using the pickle module?

```
import pickle

class MyException(Exception):
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2):
        self.arg1 = arg1
        self.arg2 = arg2

        super(MyException, self).__init__(arg1)

e = MyException("foo", "bar")

str = pickle.dumps(e)
obj = pickle.loads(str)
```

This code throws the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 13, in <module>
   obj = pickle.loads(str)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1382, in loads
   return Unpickler(file).load()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 858, in load
   dispatch[key](self)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1133, in load_reduce
   value = func(*args)
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)
```

I'm sure this problem stems from a lack of knowledge on my part of how to make a class pickle-friendly. Interestingly, this problem doesn't occur when my class doesn't extend `Exception`.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Make `arg2` optional:

```
class MyException(Exception):
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2=None):
        self.arg1 = arg1
        self.arg2 = arg2
        super(MyException, self).__init__(arg1)
```

The base `Exception` class defines a [`.__reduce__()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#object.__reduce__) to make the extension (C-based) type picklable and that method only expects *one* argument (which is `.args`); see the [`BaseException_reduce()` function in the C source](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Objects/exceptions.c#l182).

The easiest work-around is making extra arguments optional. The `__reduce__` method *also* includes any additional object attributes beyond `.args` and `.message` and your instances are recreated properly:

```
>>> e = MyException('foo', 'bar')
>>> e.__reduce__()
(<class '__main__.MyException'>, ('foo',), {'arg1': 'foo', 'arg2': 'bar'})
>>> pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(e))
MyException('foo',)
>>> e2 = pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(e))
>>> e2.arg1
'foo'
>>> e2.arg2
'bar'
```

Answer (score 58):

The current answers break down if you're using both arguments to construct an error message to pass to the parent Exception class. I believe the best way is to simply override the `__reduce__` method in your exception. The `__reduce__` method should return a two item tuple. The first item in the tuple is your class. The second item is a tuple containing the arguments to pass to your class's `__init__` method.

```
import pickle

class MyException(Exception):
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2):
        super().__init__(f'arg1: {arg1}, arg2: {arg2}')
        self.arg1 = arg1
        self.arg2 = arg2
    
    def __reduce__(self):
        return (MyException, (self.arg1, self.arg2))

# Create an exception instance and print info about it
original = MyException('foo', 'bar')
print(repr(original))
print(original.arg1)
print(original.arg2)

# Pickle and unpickle the exception, info printed should match above
reconstituted = pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(original))
print(repr(reconstituted))
print(reconstituted.arg1)
print(reconstituted.arg2)
```

More info about `__reduce__` [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#object.__reduce__).

Comment: This is the bettersauce.

Comment: This is the best answer.  The other two are really just hacks that kind of work.  This one builds the class properly.

Comment: But what would happen here id I inherit from MyException? isn't hard-coding the class's name disallows proper inheriting of this function?

Comment: @borgr Correct me if I'm wrong, but you can replace references to `MyException` inside the class with `self.__class__`. Additionally, in Python3, you can omit the args of `super`.

Comment: @nlvk I think you are correct and as this is a more complex code seems to me to be the right way to go, I suggested an edit

Comment: @borgr Sorry, but I had to revert your edit. Calling `super` with `self.__class__` is a bad practice that can break inheritance. See this gist: https://gist.github.com/ulope/1935894

Comment: Also, using `self.__class__` in the `__reduce__` method may or may not be useful since subclasses might take different parameters in their `__init__` methods. As such, I’d prefer to keep this example as simple and straightforward as possible.

Comment: @sean what would be the right practice then if some would want to be able to have inheritance? It loses a lot of the power of classes if you can't inherit (or you have to override everything). And also I don't see why in the reduce it is a problem, the error linked only happens because of the dynamically changing super class.

Comment: I didn’t mean to say there’s anything wrong with using `self.__class__` in `__reduce__`, just that it won’t work in all cases. If it will work for your use case, by all means, do it.

Comment: @Sean I don't even have a case :-) I just wondered if it is not a bad practice to create a class with a function (reduce here) with the class name hard coded, so it can not be inherited, is there any disadvantage for not hard coding the class name there?

Comment: @borgr, parent classes are inherited by their subclasses, so referring to a parent class in the method is the proper thing to do: `class MySubException(MyException): pass`. In `MySubException`, when `__reduce__` is called, since MySubException did not override the method, what is called is actually `MyException.__reduce__(obj)` and this method is referring to the `super`class of `MyException`, i.e. `Exception`. Long story short: don't worry about it.

Comment: If you look at `json.JSONDecodeError` for example https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/998ae1fa3fb05a790071217cf8f6ae3a928da13f/Lib/json/decoder.py#L20, defining a `__reduce__()` is exactly how this is done in Python's standard library.

Answer (score 18):

I like Martijn's answer, but I think a better way is to pass all arguments to the `Exception` base class:

```
class MyException(Exception):
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2):
        super(MyException, self).__init__(arg1, arg2)        
        self.arg1 = arg1
        self.arg2 = arg2
```

The base `Exception` class' `__reduce__` method will include all the args. By not making all of the extra arguments optional, you can ensure that the exception is constructed correctly.

Comment: And then override `__str__` as needed

Answer (score 1):

I simply do this

```
class MyCustomException(Exception):
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = 'Message about my error'

    def __str__(self):
        return repr(self.value)

... somewhere in code ...
raise MyCustomException
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get a custom exception with keyword-only arguments to work with pickling like this:

```py
class CustomException(Exception):
    def __init__(self, arg1, *, kwonly):
        super().__init__(arg1, kwonly) # makes self.args == (arg1, kwonly)
        self.arg1 = arg1
        self.kwonly = kwonly

    def __str__(self):
        # Logic here to turn the args into the real exception message
        return f"{self.arg1} ({self.kwonly})"

    # __repr__ and __eq__ are not needed but are nice for testing
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.__class__.__name__}({self.arg1!r}, kwonly={self.kwonly!r})"

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return isinstance(other, CustomException) and self.args == other.args

    # This is what makes pickling work
    @classmethod
    def _new(cls, arg1, kwonly):
        return cls(arg1, kwonly=kwonly)

    def __reduce__(self):
        return (self._new, (self.arg1, self.kwonly))
```

Example:

```py
import pickle

w = CustomException('arg1', kwonly='kwonly')
w2 = pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(w))
assert w == w2
```

By the way, this also works with custom warning classes, since those are also `Exception` subclasses.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to pass all of the argument to the base-class's `__init__`:

```py
class MyException(Exception):
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2):
        super().__init__(arg1, arg2)
        self.arg1 = arg1
        self.arg2 = arg2
```

(Tested with Python versions 3.6, 3.8, 3.9 and 3.10.)

Answer (score 0):

A completely generic solution is to add the following method to your exception class:

```py
    def __reduce__(self):
        return (Exception.__new__, (type(self),) + self.args, self.__dict__)
```

This works even with keyword only arguments.