# How to suppress displaying the parent exception (the cause) for subsequent exceptions

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

I'm aware of `raise ... from None` and have read [How can I more easily suppress previous exceptions when I raise my own exception in response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17091520/how-can-i-more-easily-suppress-previous-exceptions-when-i-raise-my-own-exception).

However, how can I achieve that same effect (of suppressing the "During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred" message) without having control over the code that is executed from the except clause? I thought that `sys.exc_clear()` could be used for this, but that function doesn't exist in Python 3.

Why am I asking this? I have some simple caching code that looks like (simplified):

```
try:
    value = cache_dict[key]
except KeyError:
    value = some_api.get_the_value_via_web_service_call(key)
    cache_dict[key] = value
```

When there's an exception in the API call, the output will be something like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ..., line ..., in ...
KeyError: '...'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ..., line ..., in ...
some_api.TheInterestingException: ...
```

This is misleading, as the original KeyError is not really an error at all. I could of course avoid the situation by changing the try/except (EAFP) into a test for the key's presence (LBYL) but that's not very Pythonic and less thread-friendly (not that the above is thread-safe as is, but that's beside the point).

It's unreasonable to expect all code in some_api to change their `raise X` to `raise X from None` (and it wouldn't even make sense in all cases). Is there a clean solution to avoid the unwanted exception chain in the error message?

(By the way, bonus question: the cache thing I used in the example is basically equivalent to `cache_dict.setdefault(key, some_api.get_the_value_via_web_service_call(key))`, if only the second argument to setdefault could be a callable that would only be called when the value needs to be set. Isn't there a better / canonical way to do it?)

Comment: This `defaultdict` modification should be useful to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912231/is-there-a-clever-way-to-pass-the-key-to-defaultdicts-default-factory

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have a few options here.

First, a cleaner version of what orlp suggested:

```
try:
    value = cache_dict[key]
except KeyError:
    try:
        value = some_api.get_the_value(key)
    except Exception as e:
        raise e from None
    cache_dict[key] = value
```

For the second option, I'm assuming there's a `return value` hiding in there somewhere that you're not showing:

```
try:
    return cache_dict[key]
except KeyError:
    pass
value = cache_dict[key] = some_api.get_the_value(key)
return value
```

Third option, LBYL:

```
if key not in cache_dict:
    cache_dict[key] = some_api.get_the_value(key)
return cache_dict[key]
```

For the bonus question, define your own dict subclass that defines `__missing__`:

```
class MyCacheDict(dict):

    def __missing__(self, key):
        value = self[key] = some_api.get_the_value(key)
        return value
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. Your first suggestion has the problem that 1) it potentially suppresses more than it should (perhaps there WAS a useful context within the code of the API that should be listed in the tracebank), and 2) it obscures the source of the exception (instead of seeing a module from the API as the last line in the traceback, the user will now see my code, and the API will be the last-but-one line).
Still, in the absence of sys.exc_clear(), it's my preferred solution of all those I have seen so far.

Comment: Your point about suppressing possibly useful context is definitely valid, and for that reason that suggestion probably shouldn't be used.  However, your point about obscuring the source is not valid: the exact same exception, traceback and all, is re-raised, just without its context.  I would much rather use a dict subclass with `__missing__` or the LBYL option, personally.

Comment: I find it astounding that there's no way to _prevent_ the `__context__` assignment; trying to remove it later is inherently unclean, and having to rearrange everything to be outside an `except` is gratuitously awkward.

Answer (score 0):

You can try suppressing the context yourself:

```
try:
    value = cache_dict[key]
except KeyError:
    try:
        value = some_api.get_the_value_via_web_service_call(key)
    except Exception as e:
        e.__context__ = None
        raise

    cache_dict[key] = value
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version of @Zachary's second option whose use is a little simpler. First, a helper subclass of dict which returns a sentinal value on a "miss" rather than throwing an exception:

```py
class DictCache(dict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        return self
```

then in use:

```py
cache = DictCache()
...
value = cache[K]
if value is cache:
    value = cache[K] = some_expensive_call(K)
```

Notice the use of "**is**" rather than "**==**" to ensure there is no collision with a valid entry.

If the thing being assigned to is a simple variable (i.e. "value" rather than an attribute of another variable "x.value"), you can even write just 2 lines:

```py
if (value := cache[K]) is cache:
    value = cache[K] = some_expensive_call(K)
```