# Custom exceptions with kwargs (Python)

Tags: python, exception

Is this safe?

```
class SpecialAlert(Exception):

    def __init__(self, message, **kwargs):
        Exception.__init__(self, message)
        for kw in kwargs:
            if kw == 'message':
                continue
            setattr(self, kw, kwargs[kw])
```

Related to: [Proper way to declare custom exceptions in modern Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319615/proper-way-to-declare-custom-exceptions-in-modern-python)

Butt.. Is this safe? I mean I'm overriding attributes of self?

In SpecialAlert I want to pass all kinds of things (this is an exception done for doing a long series of different checks, I do "try..except SpecialAlert as error" in a loop and then get details out of error in handlers)

I have a basic check if I'm not overriding "message", should I skip setting other attrs on self too? What are they?

Comment: Declared arguments don't end up in `**kwargs`, so you don't need the `if kw == 'message'`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This will work fine; it's perfectly cromulent to put additional attributes on an object. However, rather than checking specifically for standard attributes you don't want to clobber, just call `Exception.__init__` last, and let it clobber *yours* if you accidentally set them. Then your `__init__()` can just be:

```
def __init__(self, message, **kwargs):
    self.__dict__.update(kwargs)
    Exception.__init__(self, message)
```

Comment: Just WTF is cromulent? I thought I knew American language. ;-) Anyway, re this Exception.__init__ thing called last: perfect, but top answer on this issue I linked to does not mention that. thanks!

Comment: "Cromulent" (always preceded by "perfectly") is from *The Simpsons.* "'Embiggens'? I never heard that word before I moved to Springfield." "I don't know why. It's a perfectly cromulent word." Of course, it's debatable whether it actually means "correct" or "acceptable," or is used in an ironic sense to mean the opposite. :-)

Comment: Cromulent :DDDDD

Answer (score 4):

This is perfectly safe, you can assign additional attributes on your custom exception instance, as long as it is not `.args`.

Plenty of custom exception subclasses in the standard library do the same. For example, the `urllib2.HTTPError` exception adds `code`, `msg`, `headers`, `fp` and `filename` attributes.