# Can exceptions be written for specific errors? Like database "XXX" does not exist

Tags: python, psycopg2

I would like to write and exception for `the database does not exist`, so I can create it and return back to the top (retry the connection).

How do you get specific when writing exceptions?

Can you have two or more exceptions?

```
try:
    db_con = psycopg2.connect(host='HOSTNAME', database='MYDB', user='USERNAME', password='PASSWORD')
    cur = db_con.cursor()
    cur.execute('SELECT version()')
    ver = cur.fetchone()
    print ver

except psycopg2.DatabaseError, e:
    print 'Error %s' % e
    sys.exit(1)

finally:
    if db_con:
        db_con.close()
```

Comment: Have you taken a look at the documentation? http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html

Comment: This is also worth reading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319615/proper-way-to-declare-custom-exceptions-in-modern-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read the python documentation on [Exceptions](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html).

But generally speaking yes, you can define your own exception types just like any other class by extending `Exception` or any other appropriate error type (in this case I'd probably use `IOError`)

Example:

```
class NoDatabaseError(IOError):
      pass
```

And then in the code above the database open:

```
 try:
    open_database(database)
 except NoDatabaseError as e:
    print('Could Not Open The Database: '+str(e))
 except Exception as e:
    print('Something Unexpected Went On:'+str(e))
```

If that's not what you're asking, you should clarify your question.

Comment: That is what I'm asking, thanks for the answer. I will read the docs, thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1):

Creating your own `Exception` is just a matter of inheritance:

```
class DatabaseDoesNotExist(IOError):
    pass

raise DatabaseDoesNotExist()
```

You can also raise nested exceptions by listing one as cause for the other:

```
except psycopg2.DatabaseError as e:
    raise DatabaseDoesNotExist('message', e)     # python 2
    raise DatabaseDoesNotExist('message') from e # python 3
```

This will preserve the traceback prior to your intervention.

Comment: Ninja'd you ;) Although I forgot about preserving the traceback bit.

Comment: Haha it was a fair contest. I yield