# How to raise an exception for checking a method present in different module

Tags: python, inheritance, exception, custom-exceptions, raise

I have 4 modules.
1. run.py
Here I'm doing initialization and setup of class A and Class B.
And what I want to do is:

```
    try:
        x = x[0]()
    except TestFailure as tf:
        print tf.message
```

where due to for loop, x iterates over class A and Class B. Hence for first iteration, 1st it's doing initialization for class A and then it's doing it for B.

1. Test.py
   Here I've class Test

   ```
   class Test(object):
       IS_TEST = False
       teardown_stack = []
       td=[]
       def __init__(self):
           print "in Test init"
           super(Test, self).__init__()

       def setup(self):
           print "\tin Test setup"
           #self.add_teardown(foo)
   ```

and now

```
class TestFailure (None, msg):
message = ""
    if self.msg:
        message = self.msg
    pass
```

1. I have A.py

   ```
   class A(Test):
       IS_TEST = True
       def __init__(self):
           test_variable = 9;
           if test_variable < 0:
               raise TestFailure("test_variable is negative.")
           print "in A init"
           super(A, self).__init__()        

       def setup(self):
           print "in A setup"
   ```
2. and last module I have is B.py

   ```
   class B(A):
       IS_TEST = True
       def __init__(self):
           test_variable = 9;
           if test_variable < 0:
               raise TestFailure("test_variable is negative.")
           print "in B init"
           super(B, self).__init__()        

       def setup(self):
           print "\tin B setup"
   ```

I haven't used python exceptions before and hence I'm not familiar with them at all. How to get this work? Where exactly I'm going wrong?
I want to raise exception by this method where before doing initialization, it makes the operation happen only when test_variable is positive.

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to understand the flow of your scripts, but as far as your question regarding exception class, why not just inherit the Exception class when you create your exception class?

```
class TestFailure(Exception):
    pass
```

The rest comes from inheritance. You can find more information here: [Proper way to declare custom exceptions in modern Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319615/proper-way-to-declare-custom-exceptions-in-modern-python)