# Python user-defined exceptions to handle specific OSError codes

Tags: python, exception, user-defined

I want to handle specific OSError codes like this:

```
try:
    os.scandir()
except OSPermissionError as error:  
    # Only catch errno.EACCES, errno.EPERM
    handle_permission_error()
except OSFileNotFoundError as error: 
    # Only catch errno.ENOENT
    handle_FileNotFoundError_error()
```

Can this be done in python?

Answer (score 7):

`os.scandir()` doesn't throw these types of exceptions. It raises the [`OSError`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.OSError) exception. It does, however, allow you to determine the type of error that occurred.

There are a [large number of possible errors](https://docs.python.org/2/library/errno.html) that could be part of the `OSError`. You can use these to raise your own [custom exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1319675/189134) and then handle them further up the stack.

```
class OSPermissionError(Exception):
    pass

class OSFileNotFoundError(Exception):
    pass

try:
    os.scandir()
except OSError as error:
    # Not found
    if error.errno == errno.ENOENT: 
        raise OSFileNotFoundError()
    # Permissions Error
    elif error.errno in [errno.EPERM, errno.EACCES]: 
        raise OSPermissionError()
    else:
        raise
```

Comment: Thanks!, So it does not work to put the errno test in the subclass beforehand, sigh.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
try:
    os.scandir()
except OSError as error:
    if error.errno in (errno.EACCES, errno.EPERM): #Permission denied
        handle_permission_error()
    elif error.errno == errno.ENOENT: #File not found
        handle_FileNotFoundError_error()
    else:
        raise
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly the way my code is written. I was hoping I was missing some feature of Exception but from these answers it appears there is no such ability to include the errno test in the subclass.