# Subclass of Exception in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, python-import

I got `ImportError: cannot import name Empty` when I tried to import a subclass of Exception. Here is the code:

file name: `exceptions.py`

```
class Empty(Exception):
  """Error attempting to access an element from an empty container."""
  pass
```

file name: `main.py`

`from exceptions import Empty`

How can I fix this?

Comment: did you read this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319615/proper-way-to-declare-custom-exceptions-in-modern-python

Comment: Where are your files located, and how are you running `main.py`? Is there another `exceptions.py` file around somewhere, with different contents? The message suggests that it's not finding the `exceptions` module you expect it to find.

Comment: Try `import exceptions;print(exceptions.__file__)` to find out the path to the module and check if it's the right one.