# Default message in custom exception - Python

Tags: python, exception

I want to create a custom exception in Python, that when raised without any arguments, it will print a default message.

Code Example:

```py
class CustomException(Exception):
    pass # some code

raise CustomException()
```

and get the below output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
__main__.CustomException: This is a default message!
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The solution is given by the bellow code:

```
class CustomException(Exception):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        default_message = 'This is a default message!'

        # if any arguments are passed...
        # If you inherit from the exception that takes message as a keyword
        # maybe you will need to check kwargs here
        if args:
            # ... pass them to the super constructor
            super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        else: # else, the exception was raised without arguments ...
                 # ... pass the default message to the super constructor
                 super().__init__(default_message, **kwargs)
```

An equivalent but more succinct solution is:

```
class CustomException(Exception):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        default_message = 'This is a default message!'

        # if no arguments are passed set the first positional argument
        # to be the default message. To do that, we have to replace the
        # 'args' tuple with another one, that will only contain the message.
        # (we cannot do an assignment since tuples are immutable)
        # If you inherit from the exception that takes message as a keyword
        # maybe you will need to check kwargs here
        if not args: args = (default_message,)

        # Call super constructor
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

An even more succinct but restricted solution, in a way that you can only raise the CustomException with no arguments is:

```
class CustomException(Exception):
     def __init__(self):
         default_message = 'This is a default message!'
         super().__init__(default_message)
```

You can of course save one line, in each of the above solutions, if you just pass the string literal to the constructor rather than using the `default_message` variable.

If you want the code to be Python 2.7 compatible, then you just replace the: `super()` with `super(CustomException, self)`.

Now running:

```
>>> raise CustomException
```

will output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
__main__.CustomException: This is a default message!
```

and running:

```
raise CustomException('This is a custom message!')
```

will output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
__main__.CustomException: This is a custom message!
```

This is the output that the first 2 solutions' code will produce. The last solution, differs in that calling it with at least one argument, like:

```
raise CustomException('This is a custom message!')
```

it will output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

because it does not permit any arguments to be passed to the CustomException when it is raised.

Answer (score 55):

This is the simplest solution IMHO how to define custom exception with a default message that can be overridden if needed:

```
class CustomException(Exception):
    def __init__(self, msg='My default message', *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(msg, *args, **kwargs)
```

Usage example:

```
In [10]: raise CustomException
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
CustomException                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-259ae5202c8e> in <module>
----> 1 raise CustomException

CustomException: My default message

In [11]: raise CustomException()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
CustomException                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-c1921a8781a6> in <module>
----> 1 raise CustomException()

CustomException: My default message

In [12]: raise CustomException('Foo bar')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
CustomException                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-7efbf94f7432> in <module>
----> 1 raise CustomException('Foo bar')

CustomException: Foo bar
```

Comment: I think that this is actually the best answer.

Comment: This works great and looks elegant. However, I would like to note that pylint isn't too happy with this and calls it useless super delegation.

Comment: Also pylint reports about  keyword-arg-before-vararg

Answer (score 12):

As regarded in an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319615/proper-way-to-declare-custom-exceptions-in-modern-python), this is a pretty good way to declare a custom exception:

```
class MyException(Exception):
    """Docstring here"""
```

If one has many exceptions to define, one may use a subclass of `Exception` as their exceptions' superclass to make these exceptions' docstrings their default messages:

```
class DocDefaultException(Exception):
    """Subclass exceptions use docstring as default message"""
    def __init__(self, msg=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(msg or self.__doc__, *args, **kwargs)

class MyException(DocDefaultException):
    """Docstring here."""

raise MyException
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\************************.py", line 9, in <module>
    raise MyException
__main__.MyException: Docstring here
```

A decorator also works to use the docstring of a custom exception as its default message:

```
import functools

def docstring_message(cls):
    """Decorates an exception to make its docstring its default message."""
    # Must use cls_init name, not cls.__init__ itself, in closure to avoid recursion
    cls_init = cls.__init__ 
    @functools.wraps(cls.__init__)
    def wrapped_init(self, msg=cls.__doc__, *args, **kwargs):
        cls_init(self, msg, *args, **kwargs)
    cls.__init__ = wrapped_init
    return cls

@docstring_message
class MyException(Exception):
    """Docstring here"""

raise MyException
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\************************.py", line 16, in <module>
    raise MyException
__main__.MyException: Docstring here
```

Of course, one should raise exceptions with a descriptive message, but a default fallback is sufficient sometimes and a docstring can suffice if written correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The messages can even be dynamic. I use this to tweak some error messages in my project. Works like a charm.

```py
class PinNotFoundError(BaseException):
    """ Error class to thrown, when a pin cannot be found """
    def __init__(self, pin, *args, **kwargs):
        msg = f'Pin {pin} cannot be resolved to a pin on the device.'
        super().__init__(msg, *args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just going to throw out this solution. This will allow you to define a message with the class definition.

First a base exception class:

```
class DefaultException(Exception):
    """A class to define a default message with the exception definition"""
    MSG = ''

    def __init__(self, *args, message=None, **kwargs):
        if message is None:
            message = self.MSG
        
        super().__init__(message)
```

Now we can define exceptions with their default messages easily:

```
class CustomException(DefaultException):
    """This is just an example exception"""
    MSG = 'This is a default message!'
```

You can even modify the `DefaultException` to format the default message using the kwargs, if you want there to be some formatting as well