# Return YouTube-DL Error As Python Error

Tags: python, youtube-dl

---

I am trying to download video using YouTube-dl in python, But sometime the video i am trying to download is copyrighted or deleted, So i get an error message from YouTube-dl:

```
[Example] Example: Downloading embed webpage
[Example] Example: Downloading f webpage
ERROR: Example: File not found
```

is there anyway i can make the error stop my python program ?

Comment: Use try:  except: continue....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proper way to declare custom exceptions in modern Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319615/proper-way-to-declare-custom-exceptions-in-modern-python)

Comment: @Marcus.Aurelianus i am using this but it doesn't work.

Comment: @MoxieBall i tried this, did work :( anyway thanks.

Comment: Where does that error appear? I assume it is returned in some kind of result string, is it not? If `youtube-dl`doesn't throw an error, you might be able to do that by parsing the `result` string, searching for known error messages.