# What error should I raise when a list size is not a multiple of some value?

Tags: python

What type of error should i raise if the the size of some list is not a multiple of some value?

Consider the following code snippet:

```
def func(x: []):
    if ( len(x) % 2) != 0:
        raise WhatError("?")
    # ...
```

I have considered `TypeError`, `ValueError` and `IndexError` but I don't think any one of these fit my problem.
Are there an errortype for this type of problem or should I just bite the bullet and use one of these?

Comment: you could raise a [custom error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319615/proper-way-to-declare-custom-exceptions-in-modern-python), otherwise `ValueError` would be valid

Comment: If the documentation specifies that explicitly ("if the size is not divisible by 2 then `ValueError` will be thrown", for example) then it' snot much of a problem.

Comment: By the way `len(x)` please.

Comment: `ValueError` is typically used for this kind of thing.

Comment: From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#ValueError): "Raised when an operation or function receives an argument that has the right type but an inappropriate value, and the situation is not described by a more precise exception such as IndexError." Seems appropriate. Also remember that you can specify a more detailled cause within the error, e.g. `ValueError("Must be divisible by 2")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number of elements of a list *is part of its value*, so, among the 3, `ValueError` is the most appropriate. `TypeError` would be appropriate if it was not a list/iterable, while `IndexError` as normally used when trying to access the `x[i]` element and the list has the wrong size for that.

Answer (score 4):

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#ValueError) of `ValueError`:

> exception `ValueError`
>
> Raised when an operation or function receives an argument that has the right type but an inappropriate value, and the situation is not described by a more precise exception such as IndexError.

This seems appropriate in your case. It's also what's commonly used in Python libraries for invalid arguments, e.g. in the `math` module. Also remember that you can provide a more specific cause within the error, e.g.

```
raise ValueError("List must have even number of elements")
```

About your other alternatives: A `TypeError` seems inappropriate, as the type is correct. An `IndexError` might have been raised further down the line if the length is not even, but as you do not pass anything that works as an index to the function itself, I would not use that one either.