# How to raise my exceptions instead of built-in exceptions?

Tags: python, custom-exceptions

In some cases, I need to raise my exception because built-in exceptions are not fit to my programs. After I defined my exception, python raises both my exception and built-in exception, how to handle this situation? I want to only print mine?

```
class MyExceptions(ValueError):
    """Custom exception."""
    pass

try:
    int(age)
except ValueError:
    raise MyExceptions('age should be an integer, not str.')
```

The output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "new.py", line 10, in <module>
    int(age)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'merry_christmas'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "new.py", line 12, in <module>
    raise MyExceptions('age should be an integer, not str.')
__main__.MyExceptions: age should be an integer, not str.
```

I want to print something like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "new.py", line 10, in <module>
    int(age)
MyException: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'merry_christmas'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proper way to declare custom exceptions in modern Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319615/proper-way-to-declare-custom-exceptions-in-modern-python)

Comment: @tk421 This does not appear to be a duplicate of that question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `from None` when raising your custom Exception:

```
raise MyExceptions('age should be an integer, not str.') from None
```

See [PEP 409 -- Suppressing exception context](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0409/) for more information.

Answer (score 3):

Try changing `raise MyExceptions('age should be an integer, not str.')` to `raise MyExceptions('age should be an integer, not str.') from None`

Answer (score 0):

You can supress the exception context and pass the message from the `ValueError` to your custom Exception:

```
try:
    int(age)
except ValueError as e:
    raise MyException(str(e)) from None
    # raise MyException(e) from None  # works as well
```