# What arguments does the built-in Exception class require?

Tags: python-3.x, exception, custom-exceptions

As a followup to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55210410/creating-exceptions-that-are-co-operative), I was trying to create co-operative user defined exceptions that don't violate LSP.

I tried to search the PEPs and use PyCharm but I was unable to get a clear answer. I only found [this PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0352/), but it talks about `BaseException`, the docs state if you want to create a user defined exception, use `Exception`.

What are the required arguments that should be passed to the `Exception` constructor **without violating LSP**?

```
class StudentValueError(Exception):
    """Base class exceptions for Student Values"""
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__(*args)


class MissingStudentValueError(StudentValueError):
    def __init__(self, expression = "", error_message = "", *args):
        super().__init__(*args)
        self.error_message = error_message 
        self.expression = expression # expression that raise the exception.

    def __str__(self):
        return "Message: {0} Parameters: {1}".format(self.error_message, self.expression)
```

Comment: Could you elaborate why you think your current code violates the Liskov substitution principle.