# Python doesn't allow raising functions as exceptions but PyLint still has a check for it

Tags: python, pylint

Python doesn't allow raising functions as exceptions but PyLint still has a check for it [here](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/blob/f6df51513267072b78b208c3ce2144a1155aa299/pylint/extensions/_check_docs_utils.py#L142). Under what conditions can the above line of code be hit?

I tried raising an exception like:

```
def test_func():
    """Test-only function for checking function objects can be raised."""
    pass
raise test_func
```

But Python raises an error: "exceptions must be old-style classes or derived from BaseException, not type"

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: I am trying to test that line but it seems unreachable. How can I reach that line?

Comment: Read up on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319615/proper-way-to-declare-custom-exceptions-in-modern-python and see if it helps you, you cannot raise a function which is defined like that

Comment: Yes I read that answer. My question is then why does Pylint has a check for raising functions as exceptions and under what condition can that line be reached?

Comment: This is the commit referered to that change https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/commit/aad5ed6b519d9c8a941182bcd44fef992e193553 See if it makes sense