# Custom Errors in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-requests, custom-errors

```
class CustomError(TypeError):
  def __init__(self,message,code):
    super().__init__(f'ErrorCode:{code}. {message}')
raise CustomError("This is a sample error message!",500)
```

Okay, so I have just started learning about custom errors in python and the instructor introduced me to the concept of error code. The problem is- I don't quite understand what this fstring is doing here? What does this mean?

Comment: It's like doing `"ErrorCode:" + code + ". " + message`, I believe

Comment: f-string is not about errors, it is a feature itself https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#pep-498-formatted-string-literals.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proper way to declare custom exceptions in modern Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319615/proper-way-to-declare-custom-exceptions-in-modern-python)

Comment: It is the message yo pass to the `super` constructor. What is exactly your question? What are f-strings, or how to use exceptions?

Comment: What I'm not being able to get is- how is super constructor helping us print here?

Comment: Read about [exceptions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) - *For convenience, the exception instance defines __str__() so the arguments can be printed directly without having to reference .args.*. You simply assign the message to the `.args` and they get printed. Try `super().__init__('x', 'y')` and see the difference

Comment: Of course you are free to implement your own `__str__`

Answer (score 0):

f-strings are a formatting syntax in python. You can (for example) use braces inside a string and put expressions to be evaluated. In this case there are variable names which get formatted into the string

Answer (score 0):

Both f' and .format are format methods that are used for formatting string, f' is only applicable on strings on Python version 3.6 or more. When I use f'ErrorCode:{code}. {message}'), I am telling Python interpreter to take the string to be formatted in format, 
"Errorcode" : + code + "." + message. String format methods are used for styling input strings.

Comment: Yes. That is true. But what I'm not being able to figure out is, how is super().__init__ helping in printing that.

Comment: @SarthakGirdhar It is not. `super().__init__` is the way to call the parent constructor. The `f-string` is simply its argument

Comment: Okay, so what exactly is helping to print the the result?

Comment: You class has a parent class Type Error, from which it is inheriting,the super constructor is being used to inherit methods from super class. Type Error is a builtin class from which it ins inheriting, you can use it for defining or create your own exceptions.