# TypeError: exceptions must derive from BaseException

Tags: python, exception

I was practicing exception handling from sanfoundary and I got hanged up on a problem which had the problem statement like:

```
try:
    if '1' != 1:
        raise "someError"
    else:
        print("someError has not occurred")
except "someError":
    print ("someError has occurred")
```

It is returning an error on running which I am unable to understand, i.e.,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "M:\Prac\test2.py", line 3, in <module>
    raise "someError"
TypeError: exceptions must derive from BaseException
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "M:\Prac\test2.py", line 6, in <module>
    except "someError":
TypeError: catching classes that do not inherit from BaseException is not allowed
```

Comment: `raise "someError"` is wrong because you musy raise an `Exception` object but you're actually raising a `str` object. Does this answer your question? [Proper way to declare custom exceptions in modern Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319615/proper-way-to-declare-custom-exceptions-in-modern-python)

Answer (score 3):

In order to raise a custom exception you must implement it first, you cannot raise an exception by just naming it as a string. You can learn more about how to implement custom exceptions in this [article](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/user-defined-exception).

In this case you can simply call an AssertionError:

```
try:
    if '1' != 1:
        raise (AssertionError)
except AssertionError:
    print("AssertionError has occurred")
else:
    print("AssertionError has not occurred")
```

It's interesting to note that placing the `else` statement after `except` means that the code in that clause will run only if no error has occurred.

You call also find a list of built-in python exceptions in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html).