# How is the name of these 2 errors to be invoked in Except? (Selenium and database)

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, python-2.7, selenium

I'm putting errors in Try and Except, but I'm having trouble with 2 types of errors. I'll give you an example of what I need. This except with Valure Error works fine, because I know the error is called ValueError, so:

```
#ONLY EXAMPLE
except ValueError:
    return "FAILED"
```

**EXCEPT ERROR N.1**
The question I ask you is: how should I write for the following error? It consists of the wrong name of an html class when scraping. I wrote selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException, but the error search does not work (the script does not open at all)

```
except selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException:
    return "FAILED"
```

**EXCEPT ERROR N.2**
Same thing for the database insert error. I want to make sure that if 0 records are saved in the database then I have an error. I tried to write like this, but it's not good:

```
except  records_added_Results = records_added_Results = + 0:
    return "FAILED"
```

I wrote this because I have this code for the insertion in the database. It works correctly, I am writing it just to make you understand:

```
    con = sqlite3.connect('/home/mypc/Scrivania/folder/Database.db')
    cursor = con.cursor()
    records_added_Results = 0

    Values = ((SerieA_text,), (SerieB_text,)
    sqlite_insert_query = 'INSERT INTO ARCHIVIO_Campionati (Nome_Campionato) VALUES (?);'
    count = cursor.executemany(sqlite_insert_query, Values) 
    con.commit()

    print("Record inserted successfully ", cursor.rowcount)
    records_added_Results = records_added_Results + 1
    cursor.close()
```

How should I write? Thank you

Comment: What have you imported? If you have `from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException` you can simply use `except NoSuchElementException`

Comment: @not_speshal I imported two things: from selenium import webdriver and then from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile import FirefoxProfile. So how should I write? Thank you

Comment: Which part of your code causes the `NoSuchElementException`?

Comment: @not_speshal When with driver.get ("link"), I search for a class in a site to scrape it with SerieC_B = driver.find_element_by_class_name ("teamHeader__name"). I want to make sure that: if the class has a different name from the one I wrote (for example changed by the site over time/years), then I get the error selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException

Answer (score 1):

Import the exception before you try to catch it. Add this line to your imports:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
```

Then you can simply do:

```
try:
    #code that could raise the NoSuchElementException
except NoSuchElementException:
    #exception handling
```

For the other exception, it looks like you're trying to *raise* an exception. Consider something like this:

```
if records_added_Results == 0:
    raise ValueError("error message")
```

Comment: I thank you for the answer. Regarding the second exception, how can I put the if inside except? Just write except next to if? So: except if records_added_Results == 0:? Or is there another way? Thank you

Comment: Is it correct if I write like this? except records_added_Results == 0: return "error message" ? (I need to display the error message in a graphic window made with Tkinter )

Comment: I don't understanding why you need a `try`/`except` block. You're raising an exception. `if`/`raise` should suffice.

Comment: Read this other question of mine (not yet completed): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68333551/start-a-function-of-a-py-file-in-another-py-file-replace-icons- and-display-exce. That's why I need the exception. I am making an error check with graphics window and 2 different py files. I would like to do that if there is the NoSuchElementException error or also the records_added_Results == 0 error, in another file.py with graphics window ... the red error icon is displayed

Comment: And how does using `raise` stop you from doing that? It's still forcing an exception to be raised if your condition is satisfied. If that doesn't work, see [custom exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319615/proper-way-to-declare-custom-exceptions-in-modern-python).

Comment: Because in the other py file, that is the one with the graphics window, a code has been written that calls ONLY the except. I don't know if it includes ifs. Will your if, without except, be called anyway? Look at the code they suggested here - it's related to this one you just wrote me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68333551/start-a-function-of-a-py-file-in-another-py-file-replace-icons-and-display-exce

Comment: in the other py file, that is the one with the graphics window, a code has been written that calls ONLY the except.

Comment: It's really not that difficult. You can simply add the `if`/`raise` before `print("Record inserted successfully ", cursor.rowcount)` ?

Comment: My curiosity, just curiosity. If I write: expect records_added_Results == 0: return "message", does it work?

Comment: Because I'm on another pc and I don't have the files with me. I'll try tonight when I stay at my house. I was just wondering theoretically with Python was it possible to write this except this way:  expect records_added_Results == 0: return "message"