# Duplicate exception message: bug in asyncio?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

I have following code that do some work in `ProcessPoolExecutor` and raise the exception:

```py
import asyncio
import concurrent.futures
import platform


class MissingValue(Exception):
    def __init__(self, value_name: str) -> None:
        super().__init__(f"Missing value: '{value_name}'")


def _do_work() -> None:
    raise MissingValue("val1")


async def _main() -> None:
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as proc_pool:
        try:
            await asyncio.get_running_loop().run_in_executor(proc_pool, _do_work)
        except Exception as e:
            print(str(e))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    if platform.system() == "Windows":
        asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(asyncio.WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy())

    asyncio.run(_main())
```

I expect that it will output:

```bash
Missing value: 'val1'
```

but it output:

```bash
Missing value: 'Missing value: 'val1''
```

So, `MissingValue` wrapping twice.

Why it happens? Is it bug in `asyncio`?

Comment: This I'm not 100% sure off, but I'm pretty sure it has something to do with how Windows spawns new instances to be executed as a system process. If you switch to using `ThreadPoolExecutor` instead, it works as intended. Same goes for Linux.

Comment: you might want refer this https://stackoverflow.com/a/18108623/7887883

Comment: @PavanKumarTS Looks like you are correct.

Comment: If I replace `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor` to `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor` responce is correct: `Missing value: 'val1'`.

Comment: I checked `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor` in Linux: same duplicate output:
`Missing value: 'Missing value: 'val1''`

Answer (score 0):

If you change your class as per the link from Pavan Kumar:

```
class MissingValue(Exception):
    def __init__(self, value_name: str) -> None:
        self.message = value_name
    def __str__(self):
        return(f"Missing value: '{self.message}'")
```

The error is being returned correctly using `ProcessPoolExecutor`:

```
Missing value: 'val1'
```

Comment: It will work, but it is not a solution in general: it is a hack and sometimes I catch exceptions that was created not in my code (in a library for example).