# Proper way of making a Python file with custom exceptions

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, exception, error-handling

I'm trying to define a bunch of custom exceptions in Python for my code, and my first idea has been to create a file called `exceptions.py` where I've defined several custom Exceptions. You can see what I've done in the image.

[image]

However, as you can see, only the first class is correctly highlighted. Also, when I import this exception, it always raises, no matter if I call it or not. What am I doing wrong? What's the best practice in this case?

Thank you so much for the support.

Comment: Why do you have `print()` and `exit()` in your classes?

Comment: Please include your code as text and not as an image.

Comment: Just write `class SharepyAuthError(Exception): pass`, with the docstring. In your given code, simply defining the class calls `exit()` to exit Python.

Comment: You may find this discussion helpful:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319615/proper-way-to-declare-custom-exceptions-in-modern-python