# Python: How to raise a (custom) exception in another module than the module where it should be cought and handled?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

I know there is a lot of documentation about python exceptions, but as i'm quite new to python as well as programming in general, i'm a little bit overwhelmed with the docu i found up to now, so i would appreciate any help you can offer.

Side question: why do i need to import every Custom Exception from the module "Custom_Exception" instead of importing the whole module?

Main Question: Is it possible to use try/except and raise Exception across Modules? To specifiy: In my main script i'm calling a function inside a try/except block, the function is defined in another module. In the other module i'm raising a custom Exception, that should be detected and handled in the main sript. In my code this isn't working. How to do this correct, but not over-complex? Or is there a better way to use in this case than exceptions?

How i wanted to do it:

I have a try/except in my main_script:

```
import connect_wlan as wlan
from Custom_Exceptions import WindowClosedException

def programming_Product_xy():
    try:
        ### funtion to search for, display in a gui and connect with wlan
        wlan.display_choose_connect_network()

        ###following code...

    except WindowClosedException as e:
        print("Error", str(e))
        create_main_window()

    except Exception as e:
        print("Error", str(e))
        create_main_window()
```

than there is my module Custom Exceptions:

```
class WindowClosedException(Exception):
    def __init__(self, message="Window closed by user"):
        super().__init__(message)
```

and the Module connect Wlan, where i raise the Exception:

```
 def on_close():
        root.destroy()
        raise WindowClosedException
        print("Error: Window closed by user")
```

I also tested with using general Exception instead as well as raising the exceptions before root.destroy.

Answer (score 1):

***Side question answer***:

You can import only the custom exceptions you need. You can also import the whole module if you want, but it is especially useful to avoid ambiguity.

For example if you import 2 different functions with the same names `run` and `run` from 2 different modules `module_one` and `module_two`. That will give you more descriptive names `module_one.run` and `module_two.run`.

***Main question answer***:

If your question is about whether you can handle exceptions raised in functions created in other module, the short answer is **yes**.

According to your main file, `wlan.display_choose_connect_network()` is where you need to handle the exception (function that raises the exception if a certain condition is met).

The exception raised in `wlan.on_close` will not be handled if you do not put it in the try block.

p.s.: Unless you need extra arguments for your custom exception, it could be as simple as:

```
class WindowClosedException(Exception):
    pass
```

See [custom exception recommendations from SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319615/proper-way-to-declare-custom-exceptions-in-modern-python#answer-60465422)

p.s.2: Don't forget to put parentheses after the exception object you use to raise the exception

```
raise WindowClosedException("Window closed by user")
```