# Defining custom exceptions in Python

Tags: python, exception

This question is in reference to:

[The "correct" way to define an exception in Python without PyLint complaining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901000/the-correct-way-to-define-an-exception-in-python-without-pylint-complaining)

In terms of clean code, looks like the ideal way to define an exception would be this:

```
class MyException(Exception):
    pass
```

However as stated in the referenced question, this results in a runtime warning:

```
DeprecationWarning: BaseException.message has been deprecated as of Python 2.6
```

The accepted answer seems to be to define the message method:

```
class MyException(Exception):
    def __init__(self, message):
        super(MyException, self).__init__(message)
        self.message = message
```

Besides being 4 messier lines and less readable lines of code, the biggest issue with this is that you have to redundantly type the name of the new exception (`MyException`) twice.

I don't use classes in Python very often, so forgive me if I'm way off base here, but might a better way to handle this be to define your own base exception with a non-depreciated `.message` method since Python seems to have a problem with using the one from `BaseException`? ::

```
# Do this only once:
class MyBaseException(Exception):
    def __init__(self, message):
        super(MyBaseException, self).__init__(message)
        self.message = message

# Whenever you want to define a new exception:
class NewException(MyBaseException):
    pass
```

Comment: What was the question? I just see a statement.  Are you asking is it right?

Comment: I would go with the simple 2 liner solution...

Comment: Your problem is not about how to define it (if you don’t override default behaviour, which you don’t, then don’t override `__init__`), but apparently with how you use it, as the warning is thrown when you *access* the property. So fix it there.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that somewhere in the code you use **MyException.message**
You may change it to

```
try: 
   <some code>
except MyException as msg:
    <handle>
```